# How does Fedora preinstall apps on its operating system?

Tags: fedora

I am trying to add more apps to preinstall on Fedora, and I have absolutely no clue how Fedora can preinstall its apps so they are ready out of the box. I would like to add some more apps,and possibly remove some as well.

Answer (score 2):

In general the default installation is specified by package groups (you can use `dnf group list` in the installed system to list them), so for example there is a *Fedora Workstation* group which depends on all packages the Fedora Workstation image contains.

If you want to select packages or groups that will be installed during Fedora installation, it depends how you install your system. There are two different ways how the package installation works during Fedora installation.

**Live CD**

You can't control what applications/packages will be installed when using the Live image. After the storage is configured, the system is `rsync`ed from the Live image to the disk. The selection of packages is thus given by the Fedora variant you download (e.g. [Fedora Workstation](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/) or [Fedora KDE spin](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/en/kde/)) and it can't be changed (during installation).

**Network Installation**

With the [netinstall image](https://alt.fedoraproject.org/) you can specify what packages will be installed. The selection in the GUI installer is limited to groups, you can't select individual packages, if you want that, you need to use [kickstart](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/install-guide/advanced/Kickstart_Installations/) -- this is a "script" for automated installation, you can [manually specify](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/install-guide/appendixes/Kickstart_Syntax_Reference/#sect-kickstart-packages) what groups and packages will be installed (you can also explicitly exclude packages you don't want).

[image: Software selection during Fedora installation from a netinstall image]

Note: If you want to create a custom Fedora image, you can do that with kickstart too. See the [fedora-kickstarts](https://pagure.io/fedora-kickstarts/tree/master) which contains kickstart files used to create the official images, you can simply take one, customize it and then use [Lorax](https://weldr.io/lorax/) (or [livecd-creator](https://github.com/livecd-tools/livecd-tools) if you want the Live CD) to create the image.

Answer (score 2):

Fedora is a linux distribution with packages.

When designing the installer, they just define which packages should be included. That's it! This is done mostly through a mechanism called *kickstart files*. You can use them to fully automate an installation. (I do this to build bootable USB stick images.)

You can build your own Fedora installation using the anaconda/kickstart mechanism. It's documented [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/install-guide/advanced/Kickstart_Installations/).

In essence, it's easy. Lets start with building a *live* image, i.e. an .iso image file which you can boot from a USB stick, DVD or in a VM. (I'd recommend trying the latter, it's fun.) If that works, you can use what you've put together to install to disk.

1. `sudo dnf install fedora-kickstarts pykickstart livecd-tools` to get example kickstart files and the tools you need to build an installer.
2. You pick one of the files from `/usr/share/spin-kickstarts`. I wanted to build bootable USB sticks, so I went with `fedora-live-connamon.ks` (it's boring, and mostly contains other files to include, not really packages.). You add a `%packages` section to it, and list the packages you want to install. If you want to remove a package, you prepend it with a `-`.
3. `sudo livecd-creator --verbose --config=/path/to/your/modified.ks --releasever=35 --fslabel=myimage` will give you a file `myimage.iso`, which is bootable and contains all the files you want.

Now, test that live image: does it contain the software you wanted, does it work? If so, you can now run `anaconda --kickstart /path/to/your/modified.ks` to install it where you want :)